# Showing single data field via Google Analytics API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm having trouble displaying only a single data field via the Google Analytics API.

For example, how would I display the number of users yesterday? Or the number of users in the past week?

I'm assuming "gapi.analytics.report.Data" is the right constructor. I've tried following the "Data" code in Google's Built-in Components Reference but nothing displays on the front-end.

For the "DataChart" code, there's a "container" option that references the HTML element in the DOM that will correctly display the chart.

This "container" option is missing in "Data" - so how do I display a single data field?

EDIT: Here's the code I'm working with.

You can see a pastebin of my code here: https://pastebin.com/M6U0Bd8B

There's also a live staging version of the site here: http://madebychris.ca/dashboard2.html

The first four `section id`s are all displaying properly but nothing's showing up for the final `<p class ="report">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the raw data numbers, you can just access the response object:

```
// Set up the request
var report = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
  query: {
    ids: 'ga:XXXX',
    metrics: 'ga:sessions',
    dimensions: 'ga:city'
  }
});

// Define what to do with the response data.
report.on('success', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});

// Run the report
report.execute();
```

For example, the total's for the metrics is `response.totalsForAllResults` and the rows for each dimension are held in `response.rows`

You need to select what you want to do with the variables on the `report.on("success", function(response){` function. For example:

```
report.on('success', function(response) {
$("body > main > div > section:nth-child(4) > h2")[0].innerText = 
   response.totalsForAllResults["ga:sessions"]
});

report.execute();
```

Note: You should be able to test on the [embedded API demo](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/). Copying and pasting the initial code with the console.log should help show what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this is the exact code I've been trying (with the ID replaced) and nothing displays on the front-end.

Am I supposed to execute or display `response.totalsForAllResults`? `report.execute()` doesn't generate anything.

Comment: Thanks for following up - unfortunately, neither report.on("success",... and report.on("error",... are working. I've edited my original post with a link to the staging site for the dashboard and the code. The first four section ids all display correctly on the front-end but the <p class="report"></p> generates nothing on the front-end and I'm getting no returns on my console either.

Comment: Looking at your site, you don't have the jQuery library which would be one reason why you are not seeing the .report value update.